# Integration between alfresco and java application

Tags: java, report, integration, alfresco

I have a Java Application and I need to get a Jasper report located in Alfresco. Once I have the report I need to add some parameters and then compile it and generate a PDF.

I know this is possible, using alfresco API and Jasper Report API. I have searched in [Java-backed Web Scripts Samples](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Java-backed_Web_Scripts_Samples#SimpleWebScript.java) but I don't understand the examples, because i'm new in Alfresco and Java, so any clue would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to use alfresco-generate-reports-with-jasperreports with java backed webscript?

Comment: No, I will create the report with ireports and then upload it to alfresco.

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in Benjamin Rodriguez' [Jasper Reports Dashlet](http://code.google.com/p/jasperreports-dashlet/) which he submitted as part of last year's Dashlet Challenge. The dashlet makes it possible to configure and run Jasper reports from within the Share UI. This isn't exactly what you are trying to do but it may be a good source of example code.